# Finding the value of a trigonometric function given the value of $\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)$

Tags: trigonometry

Given:

$$\tan{\alpha} \tan{\beta} = -\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants, find:

$$\cos^2(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2})$$

in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Here is my attempt:

$$\frac{\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}}{\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}} = -\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$

$$\frac{\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta} + \cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}}{\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta} - \cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}} = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{-a^2 - b^2}$$

$$\frac{\cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)} = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{a^2 + b^2}$$

Comment: The problem is underspecified; the value of $\tan\alpha\tan\beta$ does not determine the value of $\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$. For example, if $-b^2/a^2=-3$, then we could have $\alpha=\pi/3$ and $\beta=-\pi/3$, in which case $\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$, or we could have $\alpha=\arctan(3)$ and $\beta=\arctan(-1)$, in which case $\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\neq0.25$.

Comment: Note, however, that because $2\cos^2x-1=\cos2x$, with $x=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$ we have $2\color{red}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)}+1=\cos(\alpha-\beta)$, but this is $\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta$, which is $\cos\alpha\cos\beta(1+\color{blue}{\tan\alpha\tan\beta})$.

Comment: that wont be of much help. but there should be a way to represent cos(a-b/2) entirely in terms of a and b, no?? actually this is related to ellipse, the question was "for the ellipse x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2, find the locus of the centroid of the triangle formed by the center and the points of intersection of chord of the ellipse which subtend right angle at the origin". while solving this problem i encountered this trigonometry problem

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan: You mean that $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2\color{red}{=1}$, right? Also, how did you define $\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: yes right, defined $\alpha,\beta$ using the auxiliary circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> actually this is related to ellipse, the question was "for the ellipse x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2, find the locus of the centroid of the triangle formed by the center and the points of intersection of chord of the ellipse which subtend right angle at the origin". while solving this problem i encountered this trigonometry problem

I understand how you faced the trigonometry problem.

Let $(a\cos\alpha,b\sin\alpha),(a\cos\beta,b\sin\beta)$ be the points on the ellipse. Then, we have
$$\frac{b\sin\alpha}{a\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{b\sin\beta}{a\cos\beta}=-1\iff \tan\alpha\tan\beta=-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\tag1$$

Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinate of the centroid. Then,
$$x=\frac{0+a\cos\alpha+a\cos\beta}{3},\quad y=\frac{0+b\sin\alpha+b\sin\beta}{3}\tag2$$
and so
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{3x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3y}{b}\right)^2&=(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)^2+(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)^2\\&=1+1+2(\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta)\\&=2+2\cos(\alpha-\beta)\\&=4\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\end{align}$$

Now, I think that we **cannot** represent $\cos^2(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$ **only by $a,b$**.

So, let us use another approach.

We have
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{3x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3y}{b}\right)^2&=(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)^2+(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)^2\\&=1+1+2(\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta)\\&=2+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta(1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta)\\&=2+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\tag3\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, letting $\cos\alpha\cos\beta=P$,
$$\begin{align}\sin\alpha\sin\beta=-\frac{a^2}{b^2}P&\Rightarrow \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta=\frac{a^4}{b^4}P^2\\&\Rightarrow (1-\cos^2\alpha)(1-\cos^2\beta)=\frac{a^4}{b^4}P^2\\&\Rightarrow 1-(\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta)+P^2=\frac{a^4}{b^4}P^2\\&\Rightarrow 1-\left(\left(\frac{3x}{a}\right)^2-2P\right)+P^2=\frac{a^4}{b^4}P^2\\&\Rightarrow a^2(b^4-a^4)P^2+2a^2b^4P+b^4(a^2-9x^2)=0\\&\Rightarrow P=\frac{-ab^4\pm b^2\sqrt{a^6+9x^2(b^4-a^4)}}{a(b^4-a^4)}\end{align}$$

Hence, from $(3)$,

$$\left(\frac{3x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3y}{b}\right)^2=2+2\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\cdot \frac{-ab^4\pm b^2\sqrt{a^6+9x^2(b^4-a^4)}}{a(b^4-a^4)},$$
i.e.
$$\left(\frac{3x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3y}{b}\right)^2=\frac{2a^3\pm 2\sqrt{a^6+9x^2(b^4-a^4)}}{a(a^2+b^2)}$$

Comment: awesome man!! thanks